# Retrieve ID's after bulk insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli, bulkinsert

I'm using MySQL 5.5 with PHP 5.4. I'm performing a bulk insert and need to capture all of the newly inserted ID's. This is my code:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO commodity (analysis_id, commodity_description, a_units, 
a_average_yield, a_average_price) SELECT $analysis_id, commodity_description, 
a_units, a_average_yield, a_average_price FROM commodity WHERE analysis_id = 
$import_analysis_id");
```

Is there a way to retrieve all of the new ID's of the inserted rows? Using `$db->insert_id` only returns a single ID. I would hate to have to use a PHP loop and execute several queries, but I will if I have to. Thanks!

Comment: Not possible (no known solution, I know). Could you please post an example for what you need the IDs? May be we could find another way to archive your goal...

Comment: Do you have any datetime filed in your table ? if yes then you can write simple query to get all inserted ids after particular time stamp ..

Comment: What is the field name of the "ID" you want? I am guessing it is not analysis_id. Could it be commodity_id or perhaps just id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was over thinking this. Since I'm inserting the analysis_id (eg, case number, customer number, etc.), I decided to just run a query after this one that would pull all of the ID's for the inserted analysis_id. This solved my problem.

Comment: Cool. Is analysis_id indexed then?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the auto-incremented `id`s by first selecting the highest id in your table. `id`s higher than that are new after the insert.

```
select max(id) from commodity
```

Comment: With this solution, consider using LOCK TABLES to prevent other sessions from inserting to the same table, skewing your data.

Comment: Using LOCK TABLES is a really good idea. But this my slow down the process since only one process can do this at a time.

Comment: I think Juergen is right. For InnoDB, you could use a transaction (with Repeatable Read), which would allow concurrent use of the table.